# Android: Bitmap image get reversed in Preview?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-imageview

I take the picture with camera.take picture and getting those data in on Picture taken and converted to bitmap. and then i show that in imageview.

Everything works fine when i take picture in landscape mode. if i take picture in portrait mode means, the preview image get reversed. please help me to solve this.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) responds to exactly what you mentioned

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

Comment: thank u for ur fast answer... but this works above android 4... but i working in android 2.1...

Comment: @Siva if you want to work with low api, you can use Backward Compatibility for Applications. Android is open source you can fetch the source for that functionality and add it as a library to your project